Vite compiled file fails with error during namespace mapping
I have a node.js app that I want to build with Vite/SWC.
Config file:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { VitePluginNode } from 'vite-plugin-node';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        format: 'cjs',
        entryFileNames: '[name].js' 
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    ...VitePluginNode({
      adapter: 'nest',
      appPath: './src/index.ts',

      initAppOnBoot: false,
      tsCompiler: 'swc',

      swcOptions: {
        jsc: {
          parser: {
            syntax: 'typescript',
            dynamicImport: true,
            decorators: true
          },
          baseUrl: path.resolve('.'),
          paths: {
            '@libs/*': ['src/libs/*']
          },
          target: 'es2021',
          transform: {
            decoratorMetadata: true
          }
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['@nestjs/microservices', '@nestjs/websockets']
  }
});


It compiles successfully.
However, when I execute the compiled file, the error is thrown:
Object.defineProperty(n, k, d.get ? d : {
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at _interopNamespaceDefault (pathToFile/index.js:34:39)
    at Module.<anonymous> (pathToFile/index.js:48:41)
    ...


I checked this part in the compiled code and it fails when it tries to access setMaxListeners from the process:

function _interopNamespaceDefault(e) {
  const n = Object.create(null, { [Symbol.toStringTag]: { value: 'Module' } });
  if (e) {
    for (const k in e) {
      if (k !== 'default') {
        const d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(e, k);
        Object.defineProperty(n, k, d.get ? d : { // <--- d is undefined, k is "setMaxListeners", e is process object
          enumerable: true,
          get: () => e[k]
        });
      }
    }
  }
  n.default = e;
  return Object.freeze(n);
}

The error is clear, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor will take the property of the object without iterating over its prototypes, and since setMaxListeners is a propert of the EventEmitter it returns undefined.
However, this code is generated by vite/rollup/swc and I can't control it.
How can I fix it?
